# Determining which of these has the maximum S-O Bond Length?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

> S-O Bond length is maximum in?
> (a)$\ce{SOBr_2}$
> (b) $\ce{SOCl_2}$
> (c) $\ce{SOF_2}$
> (d)$\ce{SO(CH_3)_2}$

---

Initially I thought it would be (d) since if a Halogen was attached, the S-O bond would become more polar hence shorter. But on more pondering I realised that resonance might come into play as well and there would be no resonance in (d) hence that would make the S=O bond purely double bond so (d) gets ruled out.

I'm having trouble in determining between the other 3. More is the resonance effective between S and X (where X is the Halogen atom) lesser will be the double bond character of the S-O bond.

How do we determine which resonance is more effective? Is it just related to the sizes of the respective atoms?

Also, will the S-O bond also be purely double bond in $\ce{SOF_2}$ and it would have no resonance? A friend of mine told me about this and I wasn't able to get why.

---

I would appreciate if someone could help me with approaching such problems